# Syncfusion EJ2(EJS) Schedule. Cannot populate from JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, syncfusion

I'm having trouble data binding JSON to the SyncFusion Schedule. Referring to [this article](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/documentation/schedule/data-binding/?_ga=2.161945468.1592277080.1565719333-940147558.1526408643)  In my .cshtml I have this

```
<div class="col control-section">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        @(Html.EJS().Schedule("schedule")
            .Width("100%")
            .Height("650px")
            .EventRendered("onEventRendered")
            //.EventSettings(new ScheduleEventSettings { DataSource = ViewBag.datasource })
            .EventSettings(e => e.DataSource(d => d.Url("Home/GetAppointmentData").CrudUrl("Home/SaveAppointmentData").Adaptor("UrlAdaptor").CrossDomain(true)))
            .SelectedDate(DateTime.Now).Render()
            )
    </div>
</div>
```

Home/GetAppointmentData generates the JSON as in the attached file.

```
public class AppointmentData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public string CategoryColor { get; set; }
}
```

In the browser console, I get this error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.parseJson (ej2.min.js:10)
at e.onSuccess (ej2.min.js:10)
at e.successHandler (ej2.min.js:10)
at e.stateChange (ej2.min.js:10)
at XMLHttpRequest.t.httpRequest.onreadystatechange (ej2.min.js:10)
```

I have run the content through several JSON parsers online and all of them show no error with the content. What am I missing, please?

There appears to be no format of legal JSON that will get past this error, can anyone help me

Just as I was starting to make good progress working out how the scheduler actually works because the documentation is poor, incorrect or inconsistent (or all of these).

[getappointmentdata_376cff.zip](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/245390/ze/getappointmentdata_376cff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code example and for the same below sample is prepared for your reference.

```
EventSettings(e => e.DataSource(d => d.Url("/Home/GetData").CrudUrl("/Home/UpdateData").Adaptor("UrlAdaptor").CrossDomain(true)))
```

https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ScheduleCRUD308652568